# Error 1004 when inserting formula into cell using macro

Tags: vba, insert, copy, formula

I'm trying to use a macro to insert an equation into a cell. The equation works fine if I copy it in myself but I need to copy it to 6000 cells in each or four worksheets. This question seems pretty common, but the usual answer of replace ";" with "," doesn't apply. The first line catches error 1004.

```
Range("J1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(ISERROR(F1),"",IF(ISTEXT(F1),"",F1))"
Range("J1:J6000").FillDown
```

I also tried using .formulaLocal but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to leave one quote:

```
Range("J1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(ISERROR(F1),"""",IF(ISTEXT(F1),"""",F1))"
```